# Handling a FileNotFoundError using a try and except block or an elif block if possible

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a list of drives I want to use as routing source. I want to try all of them until the function finds the valid one so as not to throw back a FileNotFoundError. How best can I achieve this? I have little knowledge of how I can tackle this scenario using a try and except block but I want something with the logic shown in the code below:

```
try:
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Source_1)
except FileNotFoundError:
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Source_2)
except FileNotFoundError:
       wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Source_3)
except FileNotFoundError:
       wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Source_4)
except FileNotFoundError:
       wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Source_5)
except:
       print("File Not Found")
```

Comment: You would need another `try` for each `except`.

Comment: Put the try / except in a loop instead so you can iterate over the possibilities, try each one, and finish iteration whenever you either 1) find the result or 2) run out of choices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wb = None
for source in [Source_1, Source_2, Source_3, Source_4, Source_5]:
  try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(source)
  except FileNotFoundError:
    continue
  except:
    raise

if wb is None:
  print("File Not Found")
```

Comment: Working but the loop is taking a long time before it reads the actual path. Any remedy?

Comment: @WisdomJamesMurombo How many files you have? is it thousands?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use a loop. But also think about other sources of error.

```
sources = [Source_1, Source_2, ...]

for source in sources:
    try:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(source)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't load the file %s" % e)
        break
    else:
        # work here with the workbook wb
        do_work(wb)
        break
else:
    print("File Not Found")
```

**Explanation:**

1. sources list will enable you to add more and more sources
2. `continue` will make the `for` loop move to the next source
3. If there is another error except `FileNotFoundError` (e.g. `OSError`, the loop will exit gracefully
4. First `else` block will work when the `try` block didn't throw exception. It'll have `wb` variable.
5. Second `else` block will execute when the for loop exhausts. In other words when none of the files were found.

Answer (score 2):

Using the comment @JacobIRR proposed, you can iterate through your sources until one works, else print the error message. Here is an example of how that can be achieved:

```py
sources = (Source_1, Source_2, Source_3, Source_4, Source_5)

for source in sources:
    try:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(source)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
else:
    print("File Not Found")
```

Comment: Working but the loop is taking a long time before it reads the actual path. Any remedy?

Comment: @WisdomJamesMurombo I assume that the actual path contains your workbook, and if that's the case then the time it takes depends on how large the file is and/or how the library handles it. The amount of time the loop would add to the execution time is negligible (milliseconds or less).

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this as @JacobIRR mentioned,

```
Sources = [Source_1, Source_2, Source_3, Source_4, Source_5]
for source in Sources:
    try:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Source_1)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        continue
else:
    print("File Not Found")
```

I guess this code should work